# Run-time Error when switch between activities in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm a beginner in Android Development. I've recently learned how to switch between multiple activities in a project. But when I run the application, it always stopped working. I tried as many ways as possible: checked the AndroidManifest.xml, checked if the case-sensitive errors exist, or changed the AVD, but it still didn't work!

Here is my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.admin.test;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button btnCallActivityB;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnCallActivityB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCallActivityB);
    btnCallActivityB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityB.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here is my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCallActivityB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Go to activity B" />
```

Here is my ActivityB.java:

```
package com.example.admin.test;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button btnCallActivityA;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnCallActivityA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCallActivityA);
    btnCallActivityA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityB.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here is my activity_b.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCallActivityA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Go to activity A" />
```

And here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.admin.test">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ActivityB"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: share your crash log with question

Comment: what is the error is shown, when you move from one activity to another ?

Comment: Please share the crash log from android monitor.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.example.admin.test, PID: 2121
                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.admin.test/com.example.admin.test.ActivityB}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: change the setcontentview in your ActivityB oncreate mathode

Comment: Please change your`setContentView()` method in your `ActivityB` Class as below. `setContentView(R.layout.activity_b)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` to `setContentView(R.layout.activity_b)` in your `ActivityB`. This will fix your problem.

```
public class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button btnCallActivityA;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);
    btnCallActivityA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCallActivityA);
    btnCallActivityA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityB.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Oh god I'm such a dumb :v
Thanks for your help <3

Comment: If your problem is solved. Do accept my answer with a green tick :)

Answer (score 2):

Please change your `setContentView()` method in your `ActivityB` Class as below.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_b)
```

Comment: Oh god I'm such a dumb :v
Thanks for your help <3

Answer (score 0):

You place `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` inside ActivityB.
Replace `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` with `setContentView(R.layout.activity_b)`.

Comment: Oh god I'm such a dumb :v
Thanks for your help <3